# How can I validate that a user input their email when using Inquirer npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, inquirer

I'm using nodeJS and inquirer to generate an html that contains the details the user enters. This is just a snippet of the code but is there something I could add to make sure that in the email question they actually give an answer in email format?

```
inquirer.prompt([
                {
            type: 'list',
            messaage: 'What is your role?',
            name: 'role',
            choices: ['Manager', 'Engineer', 'Intern']
        },{
            type: 'input',
            message: 'What is your name?',
            name: 'name'
        },{
            type: 'input',
            message: 'What is your ID number?',
            name: 'id'
        },{
            type: 'input',
            message: 'What is your email address?',
            name: 'email'
//What would go here to validate that an email address was entered?
    },
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "validate" method which validates the field with a function. Just add a Regex mail test, try this :

```
inquirer.prompt(
[
    {
        type: 'list',
        messaage: 'What is your role?',
        name: 'role',
        choices: ['Manager', 'Engineer', 'Intern']
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your name?',
        name: 'name'
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your ID number?',
        name: 'id'
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your email address?',
        name: 'email',
        validate: function(email)
        {
            // Regex mail check (return true if valid mail)
            return /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()\.,;\s@\"]+\.{0,1})+([^<>()\.,;:\s@\"]{2,}|[\d\.]+))$/.test(email);
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the relevant part of the `inquirer` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer#question), you can add a `validate` function:

```
{
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your email address?',
        name: 'email',
        validate: function (input) { // Validate here }

}
```

Now you just need to write code that will return `true` if you get a valid email address and `false` otherwise. Handling all the edge cases of email addresses results in a notoriously long and complex regular expression. There are packages you can use, if you like. A quick search turned up [`email-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator) for example. If you install it as a dependency, you can use it as your validate function.

```
const emailValidator = require('email-validator');

...

  {
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What is your email address?',
        name: 'email',
        validate: emailValidator
  }
```